# Zend Server CE Apache mod_rewrite REQUEST_FILENAME SCRIPT_FILENAME Problem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, zend-server-ce

there! I use this .htaccess file in a project:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

It works well in Apache 2.2

Recently I started to use Zend Server CE  , the ReWrite Rule didn't work !
And this works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is what Apache's document say:

> The variables `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and `REQUEST_FILENAME` contain the same value - the value of the filename field of the internal request_rec structure of the Apache server. The first name is the commonly known CGI variable name while the second is the appropriate counterpart of `REQUEST_URI` (which contains the value of the uri field of request_rec).

Anyone can figure out why? Appreciate!

Comment: No idea. Appears to contradict the Apache documentation, but since you're not using a vanilla apache, anything goes. Try to enable logging.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,EveryOne! I made a mistake, this will work:

```
   `RewriteEngine On`
   `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f`
   `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d`
   `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php  [L]`
```

It appears that FastCGI process url like index.php/anything_here  as  a true url , not index.php with pathinfo.